# Storm Trident State Implementation Txid Comparison

Tags: state, apache-storm, trident

I'm building a storm trident topology and at some point I'm using a partitionPersist stage to store data into solr. I've implemented the State class and wrote some logic to update solr using a StateUpdater. Do I at any stage have to keep track of the transaction id (txid) to make sure I don't store duplicates into solr or will trident take care of this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do have to keep track of the txid yourself.